# How can I move indented lines to the end of the previous line?

Tags: text-processing

Input:

```
Key1: value1 value2 value3
Key2: value1 value2 value3
      value4 value5
Key3: value1 value2 value3
      value4 value5 value6
      value7 value8
Key4: 
Key5: value1
```

Output:

```
Key1: value1 value2 value3
Key2: value1 value2 value3 value4 value5
Key3: value1 value2 value3 value4 value5 value6 value7 value8
Key4: 
Key5: value1
```

How can I move indented lines to the end of the previous line?

- The number of the spaces are constant in the indented lines.
- There are dozens of keys, each might have value indented in the next line.
- Values for a key might placed in multiple line

Comment: which tool are you trying to use for this? What have you attempted so far?

Comment: Is the number of spaces on the beginning of the line constant? Are the lines guaranteed to start with keyN?

Answer (score 0):

```
awk 'NR == 1 {printf("%s", $0); next}
     /^ /    {
                for(i=1; i<=NF; i++){
                  printf(" %s", $i)
                }
                next
             }
             {printf("\n%s", $0)}' input > output
```